# MySQL: Order of derived table is forgotten

Tags: mysql, derived

Sometime between yesterday and this June my hosting provider must have updated their MySQL since the following query now yields a different result than before.

I use the query as part of a union, but I have only copy/pasted the none working part - if you wonder why I'm using derived a table.

```
Select * from (SELECT c.SeatNum FROM signups c where c.SeatNum <= 5 ORDER BY c.SeatNum asc) d1
```

Earlier this query would give me the result of:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now it in stead gives me:

```
2
5
1
3
4
```

If I just do a `"SELECT c.SeatNum FROM signups c where c.SeatNum <= 5 ORDER BY c.SeatNum asc"` I again get:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Why does using a derived table all of a sudden mix up my ordering - and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: " and what can I do to prevent it" - put the order by on the outer select, obviously.

Comment: the order by needs to be on the inner select since it's part of a UNION and i dont wanna affect the order of the rest of the UNION

Comment: If no order is specified (as is the case with the outer query) then there is no order. Your previous result was (more or less) fluke. Consider adding a dummy value (e.g SELECT 1 AS dummy, c.seat_num... Etc) to the subquery (or the outer query) so you'll have something to order by later (case when dummy = 1 then seat_num...)

Comment: Great idea with the dummy value! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your table collation.  The collation type will affect your sorting results.
I generally use collation of utf8_general_ci.

Comment: It didn't help.

What i dont understand is why the order by of the inner select works fine, but then the outer select messes it up.